# computing directional derivate/ differentiability iff linear map exists

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $\| \cdot \|$ be a norm on $\mathbb R^2$ and $S= \{ x \in \mathbb R^2 | \| x \| =1 \}$, $f: S \rightarrow \mathbb R$ a function with $f(-x) = -f(x)$ for all $x \in S$. Let $F: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be defined by:

$F(x):= \begin{cases} 0 &\mbox{if}~x=0 \\ \|x\|f(\frac{x}{\|x\|}) &\mbox{if}~x \neq 0 \end{cases}$.

In a first step I want to show that for all $0 \neq v \in \mathbb R^2$ the directional derivative of $F$ at  $~0~$  exists and compute that. I know that I can do this by computing the partial derivatives but I struggled with how to use the properties of S and f.

And in a second step I have to show that F is differentiable at 0 iff a linear map $A: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ exists, such that $f(x)=Ax$ for all $x \in S$ and to compute $DF(0)$. I do not really have a clue how to put this together and will appreciate every help. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you have no assumption on the derivability of $f$, you can't use partial derivatives at all.

Comment: Ah, yes, thanks, I missed that. Could you help me with the second one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The derivative at $0$ in the direction of a vector $v\ne0$ is computed as follows:
   $$
   \frac{d}{d t}F(tv)=\frac{d}{d t}\left(t||v||f\left(\frac v{||v||}\right)\right)=||v||f\left(\frac v{||v||}\right).
   $$
   For this, you do not need partial derivatives at all.
2. If $F$ is differentiable at $0$, then the directional derivative along $v$ is equal to $a_1v_1+a_2v_2$, where $v=(v_1,v_2)$ and 
   $$
    a_j=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x_j}(0,0),\qquad j=1,2.
   $$
   Thus,
   $$
   ||v||f\left(\frac v{||v||}\right)=a_1v_1+a_2v_2,
   $$
   in particular, if $||v||=1$ (i.e., $v\in S$), then
   $$
   f(v)=a_1v_1+a_2v_2,\quad\text{in other words, }f(v)=Av,\quad A:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^1,\quad (v_1,v_2)\mapsto a_1v_1+a_2v_2.
   $$
   If this *necessary* condition is satisfied, then $F(x)=a_1x_1+a_2x_2$, and it is differentiable; thus, the necessary condition is also *sufficient*. QED.